# counting the total number of values in a vector

Tags: function, count, sum

I have a vector, a.

```
a = c(9,7,3,5,68,105,4)
```

I know that there are 7 values in this vector, but I want to calculate that in R for looping.

Using the sum function gives me the total of the entire vector, and using the cumsum function gives me the cumulative sum of the value and all preceding values for each position in the vector.

```
sum(a) = 201

cumsum(a) = 9  16  19  24  92 197 201
```

I know there is a simple solution to this, but I'm having trouble finding it.

Answer (score 0):

Use length.

```
a = c(9,7,3,5,68,105,4)
length(a)
```